# Unicode character display

Tags: microsoft-windows, unicode

Here's how some of the double-struck unicode letters display in my copy of Emacs for Windows:

[image]

Here's how they display in Notepad:

[image]

Version of Emacs:

[image]

What's a good way to get Emacs to display all of these correctly?

Comment: It's a font issue. You need one with good Unicode support. Try something like DejaVu Sans Mono.

Comment: Hi @Dan. The notepad instance in the screenshot is using 'Courier New'. If I switch Emacs to use that font, the display issue still exists.

Comment: @Dan, just to be sure, I switched to DejaVu Sans Mono and the characters are not displaying properly.

Answer (score 3):

Font names are misleading here, because when an application finds that the font it's using doesn't have a glyph for the character it's rendering, it can choose to find a different font that does. In this case, Courier New doesn't have any double-struck characters in it, so both Emacs and Notepad choose a different font that does. You can see this because although the glyphs that Notepad has rendered look nicer than the ones Emacs has rendered, Notepad has chosen a proportionally-spaced font, while Emacs has chosen a monospaced font. It couldn't find a monospaced font that had every one of those characters though, so for some of them it fell back to drawing a box with the character number in it.

To change how Emacs chooses a fallback font, you'll want to read up on Fontsets [in the chapter 22.13 of the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fontsets.html#Fontsets). [Chapter 22.15](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Modifying-Fontsets.html#Modifying-Fontsets) shows how to modify the default fontset to change what fonts it chooses for different text encodings, scripts, character ranges, etc.